# Tablet with removable keyboard for university

Tags: linux, tablet, graphics-tablet

I'm searching for a tablet with a removable keyboard and a pen to write on it. I want to use it in university where I have to write handwritten notes during lectures and homeworks. I will have to use Linux on it (maybe a Windows Linux dual boot?). It should be relatively modern such that I can use it minimum 7 years. The price range would be maximum 1200 Euro (approximately 1400$).

Comment: Are there any tablets with linux?  Would 2-in-1 like lenovo yoga do?

Comment: My first instinct with that kind of budget is a Surface devices; however, I'm a little curious as to why you want to run Linux given its relative dearth of productivity software. Is there a particular reason you want to use Linux? Is there a particular note-taking application you already use on Linux?

Comment: @OttToomet the lenovo yoga's look very interesting, I'm thinking about taking one of them

Comment: @JMY1000 for some computer science lectures it is highly advantageous if I use linux, because all my tutors use it and then it is easier to compare results. Also for coding in general I prefer linux over windows. Thats why I would probably use a dual boot again, so that I can use windows for note-taking and linux for coding.

Comment: @JMY1000 -- it very much depends on what you are doing.  In my world (stats, analytics, machine learning, coding) I would say linux has more and better accessible productivity tools.  Mac comes close and windows is lagging behind.

Comment: I think a big part of this may then come down to what note-taking software you want to use and how. First, are you planning to take notes *with your stylus* while running Linux, or just text-based/more conventional notes? While stylus/pen support on Linux certainly isn't bad, between a lack of drivers and general note-taking software you may find it's not a fantastic experience. If you're using P3X OneNote, you'll probably have an okay pen experience; Tusk/Evernote, not so much. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) If you're okay with whatever Linux note-taking software support is available for you (or using Wine), then yay, all good! There are laptops that do a reasonable enough job on Linux with styluses, and we can definitely work on some recommendations. However, if you can't find software you like with pen support (or if you just don't care about the ability to write with a pen on Linux, i.e. you're planning on using Jupyter Notebook), I think you might be better off with a separate device dedicated to note-taking. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) To be clear, it could be one that offers compatibility with your Linux note-taking app of choice (e.g. has OneNote), but if you're rebooting your laptop constantly just so you can take notes, maybe it's worth getting a second device? If you'd really prefer one device but just can't get the software to work on Linux, you could consider running Linux in a VM with a Windows host OS or something, but it seems a little kludgy to me. Older iPad Pros are pretty cheap these days, and frankly, they offer a much better experience than any of the "traditional" stylus devices.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I thought about it further and looked through some Black Friday offers. I finally bought a Microsoft Surface Pro 7. It works very nice for my purposes. I'm using OneNote for notetaking, and I'm planning on dual booting with Linux. But maybe I will use an old laptop for coding for now (I'm always working while I'm ssh'ed into a more powerful computer at my university, so I don't care about its worse performance).